# how to make a callout from a salesforce org to another salesforce org without security token

Tags: integration

i am integrating two salesforce org by soap api and partner WSDL file. when i am make a callout for session id (by calling login method) with user id and password,it requires security token.
 so how to integrate two different org without security token when org is not in my ip range.

Comment: I dont think so you can do it without security token.

Comment: Why not white-list the IP range then?

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation

> For access via the API or a client, **users must add their security**
>   **token** (or time-based token if Two-Factor Authentication on API Logins
>   is set on the user profile and the users have added a time-based token
>   to their account) to the end of their password to log in.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_concepts_security.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass the security token by allowing all IP ranges(0.0.0.0 to 255.255.255.255) in your org. Use this feature strictly for testing purposes only as it may have bad impacts in your org.

In the developer org, goto Users, Profile. Click on System Administrator then Scroll below to find Login IP ranges. Fill the complete ip range. hit save.

Ps: You cannot add complete IP range in setup>Network. There is limit on Ip range for a organization.
Cheers